# Reference button in another fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

This is probably really simple, but I can't figure it out. I have created a Bottom Navigation Activity in Android Studio. I have a button in the third tab. when the app starts, the first tab will be opened. I want to reference this button, so that when the user clicks that tab and then that button, I can do something.

This is just the automatic start activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_test, R.id.navigation_list, R.id.navigation_add)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

    // I tried to reference the button here

}
```

I tried `Button add_button = findViewById(R.id.add_add_button);`, but it returned null. Probably because I'm not in that activity. How can I reference this button? Is it good to do it in the `onCreate` or somewhere else?

Comment: You have to study the layout structure so you will understand which view is the parent of the button. When the parent view is found you call findViewById on the parent view itself. You have to reference it into a variable first.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand... the fragment is called `R.layout.fragment_notifications` How do I get a fragment into a variable and if I call the variable buttonView for example, can I go `Button button = buttonView.findViewById(R.id.button)`

Comment: Assuming that you created a project from the template, you can open the layout file corresponding to the third tab, and assign an id to the button, then edit the corresponding activity. You have to reference the button with R.id.myButton by using findViewById on the rootView.